# WebResponse Try Catch

Tags: c#

I am using WebRequest/WebResponse to grab some remote html.  When my code hits an error from the remote server, an exception is thrown.

Here is an example of my code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1";

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
string html = response.ToString();
```

The exception is getting thrown on "WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();"

If I try to wrap it in a try block, then "response" below is underlined and says The name 'response' does not exist in the current context.  Here is an example of this:

```
try
{
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
}
catch
{

}

string html = response.ToString();
```

How do I test "response" while being able to use it below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WebResponse response = null;
try
{
    response = request.GetResponse();
}
catch
{

}

string html = response.ToString();
```

You are receiving a compile-time error because your variable was declared within the `try..catch` scope and local variables can only be accessed within their scope. A scope is essentially denoted by the opening and closing brackets, everything between the brackets are part of the scope.

Specifically, the exception you receive is thrown when you invoke `request.GetResponse();`.

This means you can safely bring the variable outside of the `try..catch` scope and access it in the method scope and still catch any exceptions that might be thrown as a result of you calling `request.GetResponse();`

Comment: I tried that as well.  Then I get "Use of unassigned local variable 'response'".

Comment: @muncherelli I updated my answer. Initialize the local variable to `null`.